# What do I do when there are 2 parameters?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to find for what values of $q$ the equation $x^2-2.p.x+q-1=0$ has at least 1 root in the interval $(-2;0)$ when $p>0$.

The 2 parameters trouble me. By chance I saw that when $q=1$ the roots are $x=0$ and $x=2p$ and both aren't in the interval $(-2;0)$.

But what do I do when $q$ is **NOT** $=1$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The roots are $p+\sqrt{p^2-q+1}$ and $p-\sqrt{p^2-q+1}$. The first root is positive, so you can ignore that. So now you just have to find those $q$ for which
$$-2 < p-\sqrt{p^2-q+1} < 0$$
This gives three inequalities, all of which have to be satisfied:
$$p^2-q+1 \ge 0$$
$$p-\sqrt{p^2-q+1} > -2$$
$$p-\sqrt{p^2-q+1} < 0$$
Each of these can easily be expressed as an inequality with $q$ on the left-hand side. You will find that one of them is redundant, because it is a consequence of one of the other two.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+(-2p)x+(q−1)=0$

Plug this into the quadratic formula

$x = p \pm \sqrt{p^2 - (q-1)}$

since p>0

$p  + \sqrt{p^2 - (q-1)} > 0$ and not in our interval.

$p  - \sqrt{p^2 - (q-1)} < 0\\
(q-1)<0 \\
q<1$

and

$p  - \sqrt{p^2 - (q-1)} > -2\\
p+2 > \sqrt{p^2 - (q-1)} \\
p^2 + 4p + 4 > p^2 - q + 1\\
4p+4 > 1-q$

$-4p-3 <q < 1$

Comment: I get the same thing--OP's provided answer of $q\in(-3,1)$ must be off. Even if you were to minimize $p$, that would still not be a correct answer. Perhaps the answer should be $q\in[-3,1)$ if *any* value of $p$ is allowed, assuming $p>0$ as stated [or am I missing something appallingly obvious?]?

Comment: Choosing a simple example: $ x^2 - 16 x -17 = (x + 1)(x-17)$ has a root at $x=-1$, and $q = -16$ so $q\in (-3,1)$ is clearly not correct.

Comment: My point is more to the possibility of $q\in[-3,1)$ at least making *some* sense in the context of this problem (I'm probably trying too hard to add some rationalization of OP's incorrect answer). Perhaps OP did not state the full problem. Regardless, your answer certainly answers as much as possible concerning everything given. +1

Comment: The exact answer is when $q$ is NOT $=1$ ---> $q\in(-3,1)$

Comment: @yoloexpectz Well your "exact" answer is clearly wrong. If the condition were that $p$ would have to be nonnegative, then $q\in(-3,1)$ could make *some* sense in regards to how $(-3,1)$ is the "smallest" interval in which $q$ could be. But no matter. This answer tells everything there is to know about this problem in light of the given information.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that we also need $q \le p^2+1$, otherwise there are no real roots. Yes, this follows from $q<1$, but that is just luck.

Comment: @Tonyk, Actually not.  $p-\sqrt{p^2-(q-1)} < 0 \implies \sqrt{p^2-(q-1)}$ is real, because $<$ is not defined for the complex numbers.  When you square both sides, assume $p^2 - (q-1) > 0$

Answer (score 0):

The discriminant is $d=p^2 - q + 1$. So a necessary condition is that $d\ge 0$, or $q\ge p^2+1$. On the other hand, $x=\pm \sqrt{d}+p$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to find real roots of this equation.

Given $ax^2+bx+c=0$, then $D=b^2-4ac$ and if $D>0$ there exists two real roots, if $D=0$ then there is single real root, and else none. If roots exist they are given by $x_{1,2}=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt D}{2a}$.

So for $x^2-2px+q-1=0$ we have $D=4p^2-4(q-1)=4(p^2-q+1) \geq 0$ as necessary condition and since roots are given by $x_{1,2}=\frac{2p \pm 2\sqrt{p^2-q+1}}{2}$ you may compare them with given interval $(-2,0)$ and find the answer.

Comment: The answer is $q$ is in $(-3;1)$ I don't see how I can get it.